# Webpack-Dev-Server not showing latest files on change

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to get a project running that uses a webpack dev server with HMR and source-mapping but am running into an issue. When I use webpack alone with my configuration file the source-maps are indicated in the console output and HMR works on page-refresh, but there is no server. When I try to instead run the script using webpack-dev-server there is no indication in the console that source-maps are being generated and changes are not being rendered ( either automatically or on page refresh ) when recompilation is appearing in the console output.

Here is my configuration file

```
/*
    Webpack Configuration File
    webpack.config.js
    ===
    Webpack configuration file for the, "Debugging Webpack Issues" project.

    @version:0.1.1

*/

const webpack = require( "webpack" );
const path = require( "path" );
const htmlWebpackPlugin = require( "html-webpack-plugin" );

const BUILD_PATH = path.resolve( __dirname, "../build" );
const SOURCE_PATH = path.resolve( __dirname, "../src" );
console.log(BUILD_PATH);
console.log(SOURCE_PATH);

let config = {
    entry: SOURCE_PATH + "/index.js",
    output: {
        path: BUILD_PATH + "/rsc/scripts/",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                options: {
                    "presets" : [ "es2015", "react" ]
                },
                exclude: [/node_modules/],
                include: SOURCE_PATH
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [ "style-loader", "css-loader" ],
                include: SOURCE_PATH,
                exclude: [/node_modules/]
            }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        compress: true,
        port:9000,
        open: true,
        hot: true,
        contentBase: BUILD_PATH
    },
    devtool: "source-map",
    watch: true,
    target: "web",
    plugins: [
        new htmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: "Example React App",
            filename: "../../index.html",
            template: SOURCE_PATH + "/template.html" 
        }),
        new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

I am aware that webpack-dev-server may not be updating because it is trying to load from a static location, but I have attempted changes to my file that others specified in their projects ( such as adding publicPath to the file ) with this issue without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webpack's `publicPath` value needs to be relative to the build directory in the output.

Here is a working version of my webpack configuration file :

```
/*
    Webpack Configuration File
    webpack.config.js
    ===
    Webpack configuration file for the, "Debugging Webpack Issues" project.

    @version:0.1.1

*/

const webpack = require( "webpack" );
const path = require( "path" );
const htmlWebpackPlugin = require( "html-webpack-plugin" );

const BUILD_PATH = path.resolve( __dirname, "../build" );
const SOURCE_PATH = path.resolve( __dirname, "../src" );
const PUBLIC_PATH = "/rsc/scripts/";

console.log(BUILD_PATH);
console.log(SOURCE_PATH);

let config = {
    entry: SOURCE_PATH + "/index.js",
    output: {
        path: BUILD_PATH + PUBLIC_PATH,
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                options: {
                    "presets" : [ "es2015", "react" ]
                },
                exclude: [/node_modules/],
                include: SOURCE_PATH
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [ "style-loader", "css-loader" ],
                include: SOURCE_PATH,
                exclude: [/node_modules/]
            }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        compress: true,
        port:9000,
        open: true,
        hot: true,
        contentBase: BUILD_PATH,
        publicPath: PUBLIC_PATH
    },
    devtool: "source-map",
    watch: true,
    target: "web",
    plugins: [
        new htmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: "Example React App",
            filename: "../../index.html",
            template: SOURCE_PATH + "/template.html" 
        }),
        new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

Anyone with this problem should make sure that a `publicPath` is set in the `devServer` configuration options. The `publicPath` should be treated as the path ( relative to the build directory ) that your Server's html file should look to grab `bundle.js` from.

My project structure in my Build folder looks like:

```
./build
./build/rsc/scripts/bundle.js
./build/index.html
```

so my `publicPath` needed to be set to `/rsc/scripts` so that it knew where to get the virtual file from.

Answer (score 0):

In my case , project was generated by create-react-app.
My solution is:

Find
./node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpackDevServer.config.js

locate below code:

```
    historyApiFallback: {
  // Paths with dots should still use the history fallback.
  // See https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/387.
  disableDotRule: true,
  index: paths.publicUrlOrPath,
},
```

Remove the above code, and update the above as below:

```
    historyApiFallback: true,

hot: true,
```